# Jquery Internet Explorer 8 compatibility issue, does not load data unless history is deleted

Tags: jquery

Hey guys, I have a weird problem. I have an update system that refreshes data on a time interval. It works well in all browsers except internet explorer 8. The problem is that once it loads the data, it does not matter if the data updates further, it will not update the data visually until the internet history is cleared. I am not using any cookies server-side...Anyone ever encounter something like this?

Here is my javascript, thanks for any assistance in advance

```
function prepare(response) {
          var d = new Date();
          count++;
          d.setTime(response.time*1000);

          var mytime = d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds();
          var string = '<li class="shoutbox-list" id="list-'+count+'">'
              + '<span class="shoutbox-list-nick"><a href="statistics.php?user='+response.user+'">'+response.user+'</a></span>'
              + ' <span class="date">'+mytime+'</span><br>'
              + '<span class="msg">'+response.message+'</span>'
              +'</li>';

          return string;
        }
 function refresh() {
          $.getJSON(files+"shoutbox.php?action=view&time="+lastTime+"&topic_id="+topic_id, function(json) {
            if(json.length) {
              for(i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(json[i]));
                $('#list-' + count).fadeIn(1500);
              }
              var j = i-1;
              lastTime = json[j].time;
            }
            //alert(lastTime);
          });
          timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
        }
       $(document).ready(function() {

            var options = { 
              dataType:       'json',
              beforeSubmit:   validate,
              success:        function(response, status){
                  if (response.error=='success'){
                     success(response, status);
                  }
                  else {
                      $.prompt(response.error);
                  }
              }
            }; 
            $('#daddy-shoutbox-form').ajaxForm(options);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 100);


        });
```

Comment: does your query string change? I seem to recall that IE would sometimes cache AJAX GET requests if the url didn't change. PS you can use Fiddler to verify if they are getting cached.

Comment: yeah I just attached a timestamp to the url like the guys below suggested.

Comment: IE always caches get requests to the same URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a caching issue. Try appending a random string to the URL to ensure that it gets changed.

```
var url = 'example.php?foo=bar&r=' + Math.random();
```

Comment: I would simply append a timestamp instead of a random number: `"...&t=" + (new Date()).getTime().toString();`

Comment: Heh. It's probably pretty obvious that I haven't had to deal with this sort of thing very often.

Comment: Well, +1 anyway, because you had the right idea. Another thing -- this caching thing has happened in IE6, IE7, and IE8 for me, so this is my default solution. I'm not sure why jQuery doesn't just build this into their framework as a configurable option.

Comment: The timestamp worked thanks everyone for your help, really appreciate it, you guys are great.

Comment: An even shorter method is `var url = 'example.php?foo=bar&r=' + (+new Date());`. The unary operator `+` converts `new Date()` into an integer, which is then cast as a string automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably check your cache control on the server, this seem to in cause here. You can probably add a "no-cache" http header to your result.

Comment: Somehow I always forget that there are non-hacky solutions to certain problems. +1, leaving answer for reference.

Comment: thanks anyway man, but I tried denying caching and it did not work properly. Maybe I did it wrong, I used a php header
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

Comment: Did you check the headers sent by the server? You can do it easily with Firebug or the IE developper tool.